# Automatically generate meta tags for all the woocommerce produts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

product short description as a meta description automatically in wordpress (woocommerce plugin). Is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

Try This:
You need to add meta in head tag with help of action called `'wp_head'`

**in function.php**

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_product_meta');
function add_product_meta() {
 if (is_single()) {
 global $post;         
 $post_excerpt =  $post->post_excerpt;     
?>
<meta property="your_property" content="<?php echo $post_excerpt; ?>" />    
<?php }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should i add this into function.php??

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply vrajesh. Its working for me.

Comment: please make my answer as solution by ticked(clicked) right beside my answer :).thx.

Answer (score 2):

Above code will place whole product description as meta description which is not good. Try This code. I just edited the above code to reduce the number of character because according to google guidelines meta description should not be more than 170 characters.

```
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_product_meta');
    function add_product_meta() {
    if (is_single()) {
    global $post;         
    $post_excerpt =  $post->post_excerpt; 
    $a= $post_excerpt;
    $des = substr($a, 0, 170);    
    ?>
    <meta name="Description" content="<?php echo $des; ?>" />    
    <?php }
    }

    ?>
```